# Uncheck Checkbox (That Saves State in Database) in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox

I've got a checkbox that saves its state (Checked/Unchecked) in a MySQL Database. For example there's one at https://encrypted.coxnetworks.co.uk/school/includes/Checkboxes/Monday1/checkbox.php (it's password protected).

The code on the page is

```
<form id='checkbox' method="post" action='/school/includes/Checkboxes/Monday1/checkbox.php'><!-- php: get the name+location of the webpage -->
    <input type="hidden" name="confirm" value="1"> <!-- give confirm a value -->
    <input type="checkbox" checked name="checkbox" value="1" onclick="document.forms['checkbox'].submit()"/> <!-- submit the form when checkbox is clicked -->
</form>
```

So it's using javascript to post to PHP. However I want to be able to click one button to launch a script to uncheck a load of these. How could I do this?

Comment: They're 'included' via iFrames though, not directly in the page, so the javascript solutions don't really work. Sorry should've said that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple forms, you can do this with jQuery's AJAX:

```
$(function() {
   $('input.save_state').change(function)() {
      $.ajax({
         url: '/path/to/controller',
         type: 'POST',
         // Send both the ID and the boolean value
         data: 'id='+$(this).attr('id')+'&val='+$(this).val(),
         success: function() {
            // show success message if necessary
         }
      });
   });
   $('button.wipe_all_states').change(function)() {
      $.ajax({
         url: '/path/to/controller',
         type: 'POST',
         // Because you're resetting everything, you don't need to send IDs or values
         success: function() {
            // show success message if necessary
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using jQuery. This will allow you to use a simple script like:

```
$('input[type=checkbox].uncheck').attr('checked',false);
```

This would uncheck all checkboxes with the class "uncheck".

You can find jQuery at:

http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Something to the extend of

javascript alone:

```
function checkAll(field)
{
for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
    field[i].checked = true ;
}

function uncheckAll(field)
{
for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
    field[i].checked = false ;
}
```

or a jquery rendition may look like:

```
$(".fieldClass").attr("checked", "checked"); // make checkbox or radio checked 
$(".fieldClass").removeAttr("checked"); // uncheck the checkbox or radio
```

this is for just checking/unchecking mind you.. the posting of the data you would just handle the way your doing now I suppose.